# Trigger Textview when clicked on ListView

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm a noob Android developer. I learned of the basic UI controls and different types of views that I can utilize.

Now my problem is, I need to show list of items using the ListView that is being shown full screen. when I click on an item it should load a TextView full screen. when I click the back button it should go back to ListView again..

Can someone point me where I can learn such stuff?? any support or even external link is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your text view in a different activity. And when ever you click on a list item start that activity putting your text in the intent. Fetch the text in that text view activity in onCreate()  from the intent and set it to text view. Obviously when ever you click back you 'll come back to list view activity.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this website... http://www.xtensivearts.com/topics/tutorials/

He's no longer updating but what you've asked is covered in the video tutorials he did create. It's not answered directly but by watching them, you should have a solid enough understanding to piece it together yourself.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try it myself today :)